# screenshot via adb in Amazon Kindle Fire HD

Tags: android, adb, screen-capture

Actually, there is no screencap utility out of box in Amazon Kindle Fire HD. Id'like to install it to /system/bin/ via adb to call from the command line (still via adb) at the moments when I need to have a screenshot and logcat is not enough to attach the to bug description.

There are some descriptions how to use screencap utility for such purpose: http://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/152122/ 
(see

```
adb shell screencap /sdcard/screen.png
adb pull /sdcard/screen.png screen.png
adb shell rm /sdcard/screen.png
```

)

However, it seems that my device uses Android 2.3 Gingerbread, so there is no screencap utility out of box. So, the question are 1) Is there a way to push screencap of other Android versions to /system/bin/ 2) where I can download it online?

Other approaches working with adb shell are welcome.

Comment: if you it's for development/bug reporting/etc. can't you use *Screen Capture* button in the *DDMS* perspective of the Eclipse ADT? or don't you use ADT, only pure ADB?

Comment: unfortunately, android sdk utilities doesn't detect the device on my debian machine. Instead, android-tools-adb package was installed and works fine. Since, as there is no other utilities than pure adb coming with android-tools-adb, I have to use pure ADB only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know exactly if this will help you, but I once happened to find out several other ways of capturing a screenshot. From what I know, they do not depend on the `screencap` but rather on the ADB daemon. All of them require your device to have USB debugging turned on.

- I would really suggest trying this simple utility out: http://www.roman10.net/a-program-for-taking-screenshot-for-android-device-from-command-line/ which essentially reimplements the DDMS screenshot functionality without the whole GUI. It automatically writes it on your computer so there's no need for push/pull. It's pure Java so it's a great bonus.

  Scroll down to the download section where you can download just the binary and test it out.
- Another method would be to use MonkeyRunner described here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html. All you need to do is write a simple script which captures the screen, which is shown on the page from the link.

  Unfortunately I don't know if `android-tools-adb` provides MonkeyRunner.
- Another tool is *Android Screenshots and Screen Capture*: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot/

  It just needs the Android SDK installed and I suspect it runs on the same principle as DDMS or the first program - from Roman10.

Hope that helps!

Comment: another method came to my mind: if that doesn't help please check if your device is rooted - if it is, *AirDroid* application can capture the screen on the device and send it to you via a (very!) comfortable browser interface.

Comment: Thank you! Roman10 utility helped so much! it also gave some ideas for automated testing of the whole system (I will not rely on MonkeyRunner for that purpose, since it should be more complex automation testing taking into account both web, social-networking, so it will be orchestrated from the desktop machine, but with some mobile device attached to accelerate those tests)

Comment: cool stuff :) I'm glad it worked. thanks for sharing the results!